# PKCS#11 Sessions

Tags: pkcs11, smartcard

I am maintaining an application that uses PKCS#11 to talk to a smartcard. Somehow a session gets generated, but i cant figure out where in the code.

I am using c# and the [PKCS11Interop](https://www.pkcs11interop.net/) wrapper. The funny thing is that if in my main application i do a `slot.GetTokenInfo()` i can see that there is one session open, but if i create a test project and do the same thing there, `GetTokenInfo()` on the same slot, it shows that there are currently no sessions open. Does the smartcardreader somehow only show the current process active sessions, and not the total number of open sessions?

Comment: For clarification: What smartcard-reader model are you talking about? What software exactly are you using to talk to it? And (most important) are you sure this is about cryptography and not simply a *“programming”* or a *“help me understand the hardware”* question? Somehow, the question doesn’t seem to fit [*what our help center describes*](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)! But… I know some users have an indeep knowledge when it comes to smartcards and crypto, so I’ll leave this open for the community to decide if they think it’s indeed *off-topic* or if they want to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions in *PKCS#11* are always specific to the current process, so it is no big surprise that you cannot see the session from a different one.